# How to use getMapping function of Elasticsearch JS

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I am trying to use this getMapping function seen [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-getmapping) in the api. I am trying to get the mapping for an index in my database. So far I've tried this

```
var indexMap = client.indices.getMapping(['indexName'], function() {
        console.log(indexMap);
    });
```

and

```
var indexMap = client.indices.getMapping({index: 'indexName'}, function() {
        console.log(indexMap);
    });
```

both tries fail and log `{ abort: [Function: abortRequest] }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I took a closer look at the ElasticSearch JS [Quick Start](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/quick-start.html) docs to see how they were using the methods. I was confused by the API because I thought it was supposed to take an array `client.indices.getMapping([params, [callback]])`. But I now understand that it takes an object with params inside that object and then returns the response in a callback. The function does not return anything relevant as far as I can tell. Heres the code I used to get the mapping on 'myIndex' index. The mapping is stored in the response object.

Code:

```
client.indices.getMapping({index: 'patents'}, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Any idea how to call ES getMapping function using node js.